# Gradle problem getting developer certificate

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, huawei-mobile-services

I have a problem when ever I build my flutter app, the problem occurs when the Gradle tries to build and calls for the resources:

> Certificate for <developer.huawei.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [a248.e.akamai.net, *.akamaized.net, *.akamaized-staging.net, *.akamaihd.net, *.akamaihd-staging.net]
> this happens when trying to build my gradle app

I tried fetching the cert from the huawei.com and implement it on the jdk using the key tool.
Ii also tried upgrading Gradle to the latest version.